# How to revive my bay tree after heat wave / drought?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

We live in London and went in holiday for 2 weeks and London had a heatwave. Now my bay tree looks like this, how can I recover it?

[image]

---

Update:
To update you all, I ended up leaving it a bit longer and eventually it started to regrow. It's a bit of a monster at the moment but I'm hoping with time it will recover.

Thanks Bamboo and Musser for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear, that's a bit of a disaster, isn't it. Obviously, keep it well watered, but if the topgrowth gets any drier and browner and starts falling over the next 5 days, cut it all down, because by then, the best you can hope for is it regrows off the roots. With any luck, the roots haven't given up, its just sacrificed its topgrowth in order to survive. I think it's unlikely it will look good even if the top starts growing again, too much dead stuff which won't recover, so you could decide to just cut it down now.

I'm a bit puzzled though,, thinking about it - I live in London, and the heatwave ended two weeks ago, so if you've been back two weeks and it still looks this bad, cut it down now.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say we got back a month ago!

Comment: should I cut it to the base? Or leave the main stalk and cut the branches ? Or just cut the dead leaves off? Or...  ?

Comment: Cut the whole thing down to about an inch or two UNLESS you spot any new growth coming off the main, central stem - if you do, cut it back to that.

Comment: Also might use a scratch test if i were to look for life in it. Bummer, looks like it was a nice plant.. at this point the extremities will probably just continue drying if it stays in sun.

Comment: @Bamboo see below it's growing again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well it doesn't look too bad at all - just cut out the dead at the top,back to where its growing either side,and get rid of the dead sideshoots.